# Manipulate data in an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out how to manipulate data that's in an array in JS.

Currently I have this:

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([
                {$match:{date:{$gte: new Date(fuelStart), $lte: new Date(fuelEnd)}}},
                {$group:{_id: '$truckNumber', 
                         comdataPurchase:{$sum: '$comdataPurchase'},
                         defTotal:{$sum: '$defTotal'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                    fuelArray = data;
                    console.log(fuelArray);
                    fuelArray.forEach(function(_id){
                        console.log(fuelArray['comdataPurchase']);
                    });
                });
```

I cant seem to figure out how to access the data within an array within the array.

I want to take the output:

```
[
  { _id: 567130, comdataPurchase: 525.49, defTotal: 38.79249 },
  { _id: 567132, comdataPurchase: 1050.98, defTotal: 77.58498 }
]
```

And subtract the defTotal from comdataPurchase.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Wow I am special lol

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([
                {$match:{date:{$gte: new Date(fuelStart), $lte: new Date(fuelEnd)}}},
                {$group:{_id: '$truckNumber', 
                         comdataPurchase:{$sum: '$comdataPurchase'},
                         defTotal:{$sum: '$defTotal'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                    fuelArray = data;
                    console.log(fuelArray);
                    fuelArray.forEach(function(data){
                        console.log(data.comdataPurchase-data.defTotal);
                    });
                });
```

Solved